# ios privacy settings in phonegap app

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, native

Turn off location services on ios iphone.

App tries to get location using geolocation.

if not get geolocation on app than 'Turn On Location Services..." message that shows "Settings" and "Cancel" buttons.

if user will click on "settings" button than will direct open ios privacy setting(not manually).

I have using jquery mobile, phonegap, html5, css3

please help me friends

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for ios < 5.1;

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done from phonegap. There never was an implementation of that functionality in phone gap. It was available to native apps until version 5.0, but Apple removed the App Settings URL scheme in 5.1.